# Is comparing terms in a series sufficient to show that it is decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In a question I was required to use the alternating series test to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ converges.

To show that $\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ is a decreasing sequence I compared the terms $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}$ and said that

$\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2 + 1} \lt \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ for $n\to\infty$ but got this wrong. I am unable to consult my professor and wanted to find out why this might be a wrong assumption.

Comment: You should use the first derivative test and show that it's negative.

Comment: $$\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n^2+1}$$ if and only if $(n+1)(n^2+1) < n((n+1)^2 + 1)$, or equivalently $n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 < n^3 + 2n^2 + 2n$, which is the same as $1 < n^2 + n$. This is clearly always satisfied for positive $n$. Can you explain what you mean by saying that you "got this wrong"?

Comment: @Bungo This was in a test and I got a mark docked off because I used this rather than using the first derivative test. I understand that the first derivative test would have been more suitable but I believe this still shows what was required. Before I present my case I wanted to find out if my understanding was generally wrong or if I was marked down because I didn't use what was preferable.

Comment: Assuming your explanation was similar to my previous comment, I think you have a case, unless the question explicitly asked you to use the first derivative test. However, if you simply stated that $\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2 + 1} < \frac{n}{n+1}$ without supplying a proof/justification, then that might explain why you lost points.

Comment: "*said that $\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2 + 1} \lt \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$ for $n\to\infty$*" Maybe you should post how exactly you proved that. The part "*for $n\to\infty$*" is a bit odd, since the inequality holds for $\forall n \ge 1$.